# Stop a httpwebrequest?

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, webrequest

I made a httpwebrequest in a sub. The form on my program has a start button which calls the sub. I want to add a Stop button to it to stop the httwebrequest if the user so chooses.

How would I do this?

Comment: Since you've tagged this with `C#`, I assume by "sub" you actually mean "function" or "method"? C# does not use any of those keywords, unlike VB.NET, which uses `sub` and `function`, but they are generally all called `functions` or `methods` in C#

Answer (score 5):

Call [`Abort`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.abort.aspx) on the HttpWebRequest.

BEWARE that this might cause some strange behaviour... for example: depending on how you made the request and in what state it is this might lead to a deadlock.

Comment: How would I call it? Using an if statement saying if the button was clicked to abort?

Comment: @user1017524 to answer that you need to show your source code... otherwise I would just speculate...

Comment: How would I set up an if statement inside my sub to check if the button was clicked?

Comment: @user1017524 I don't understand... you say you are using C# - in C# there is nothing called sub. you are talking about some `if`statement - why don't you use an event handler ?

Comment: Nevermind I figured it out. I created an int, made it equal to 0. Then when the stop button is clicked the int = 1. So in my request I set up an if statement saying if the value of the int is greater than 0 to abort. Then I make the value of the int = to 0 again :)

Answer (score 2):

You could use the `HttpWebRequest.Abort()` method to stop your HTTP request.

Please see the following [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.abort.aspx) link for an example.